# ImageButton OnMouseOver Call C# function

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton, onmouseover

I have a problem with an Image Button and its `onmouseover` action.

In my ASPX file I have something like:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dosth() {
        document.getElementById("btnload").click();
    }
</script>
```

...

```xml
<asp:Panel ID="pnUp" Height="200px" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

...

```xml
<asp:Button ID="btnload" runat="server" OnClick="btnload_Click"
    Visible="false" />
```

...

And in my ASPX .cs file something like:

```cs
ImageButton btnImg = new ImageButton();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnImg.ID = "btnImg";
    btnImg.ImageUrl = "images/imgbutton.png";
    btnImg.CssClass = rblSize.SelectedValue.ToString();
    btnImg.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "dosth();");
    pnUp.Controls.Add(btnImg);
}

protected void btnload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // stuff to do
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Do you know how to run C# function in `onmouseover` action. The JavaScript function `dosth()` is executing, but still it doesn't run the click function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referencing ID's of ASP.NET server controls via JavaScript, you must use the `ClientID` attribute of the control.  The `ClientID` attribute outputs the full client side ID of the control.

This should work:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dosth() {
        document.getElementById('<%=btnload.ClientID%>').click();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any JavaScript errors?

I think your problem is that you are using the wrong id to lookup the `<img>` tag in your JavaScript.

In ASP.NET, the client-side id is automatically generated to ensure it is unique.

You have two options:

**Option 1:** Set `ClientIDMode` to `Static` in your `btnload` definition.

```xml
<asp:Button ID="btnload" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
    OnClick="btnload_Click" Visible="false" />
```

This way, the client-side id of `btnload will` be `"btnload"`.

**Option 2:** Change your JavaScript to insert the generated client-side id.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function dosth() {
    document.getElementById('<% this.btnload.ClientId %>').click();
}
</script>
```